# Magento 301 Redirection having multiple redirects Nginx Server

Tags: magento-enterprise, url, url-rewrite, nginx

We have migrated a website from the .NET platform to Magento. We have changed the URL structure of both websites hence the old URL needs to be redirected to New URL.

For example:

1. Old URL: http://www.example.com/p-20912-nutrasec.aspx
2. New URL: https://www.example.com/nutrasec

Many of our old URL are HTTP which needs to be redirected to HTTPS. I have used the Magento URL Custom Rewrite feature to perform redirection. The redirection performed is 301 permanent. Please check the screenshot below

[image]

Though redirection works we are getting multiple redirections for it ie:

1. When user opens http://www.example.com/p-20912-nutrasec.aspx it is redirected [301] to http://www.example.com/nutrasec
2. And then again a second redirection is occurred to https://www.example.com/nutrasec which is [302]

This is a huge problem. The configuration done in the admin is as below:

[image]

We are using nginx server. It seems to be a problem with Magento Redirection. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: nice to see your nginx part of config. and is your unsecure base url with HTTPS<---- as you have https redirection, this will help a lot.

Comment: yes, both base secure and unsecure URL are HTTPS..

Comment: also nginx config just to be sure, redirect part

Comment: I am not sure about nginx config.. from where should i extract it.. I am not expert in server handling

Comment: how exactly you are going to debug and fix it then? :P

Comment: I contacted server guys and they say its a problem with Magento so here i come back to debug it with Magento... I have resolved 302 issue by tweaking default redirection to 301 rather then 302.. Next the multiple redirection is a problem

Comment: then sounds like your magento doesnt know during rewrite that frontend is **https** for unsecure base url

Comment: I have made both secure and unsecure URL as https, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: im not sure if old product url is only different with `p-20912-(PRODUCT_NAME).aspx` so easier to cut it at nginx and rewrite to correct product page. it will be even faster to map all your catalog old->new in nginx